# Redo queryset if is empty and pass the information to template

Tags: django, django-queryset

In a View a I modified the queryset to filter by name:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
 qs = super().get_queryset()
 if self.request.GET.get('q'):
            qs = qs.search_by_keyword(self.request.GET.get('q'))
 return qs
```

If there are no results to the filtered by q Queryset, I want to execute the default queryset, but also pass to the template that I done so.

I know how to check in `context` if I have a query filtered by 'q', but this doesn't tell if the 'q' filtering query was empty or not(no results to the search parameter), and because of that I call the default query.

So, there are 2 steps:

```
- detect that a queryset was empty and call the default queryset
- pass to the template a variable to tell that the initial queryset was empty and I call the default query
```

An example if someone search for `q='keyword'` , and the returned queryset is empty, and I want the default queryset to be executed with all items.

I need to know in the template because I want to tell the user, we didn't found what you are searching so we are showing you all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set instance attribute in `get_queryset` and check it in`get_context_data` method:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    self.query_modified = False
    if self.request.GET.get('q'):
            qs = qs.search_by_keyword(self.request.GET.get('q'))
            if qs.exists():  
                self.query_modified = True
            else:
                qs = super().get_queryset()  
    return qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['query_modified'] = self.query_modified
    return context
```

Comment: in the case the query from q filtering is empty I want to execute the default query; in your example you just check if is the default query or the one with q filtering, not if q filtering got no results and the normal query was called after the initial query

Comment: @user3541631 ah, I understood your problem wrong. Check updated answer.

Comment: the second solution does the same thing; if q exist and is 'word' the query_modified return always true even if the qs is empty or not; I want if qs for q filtering is empty to execute the default qs; i updated my question with an example, please check

Comment: @user3541631 one more try:)

Comment: isn't qs.exist execute the queryset again ? I can say if qs but I think this is executing the query before returned and I don't know what happening in backend

Comment: @user3541631 Yes `exists()` execute additional query, but it's fastest way to check ifqueryset contain any data. From docs:  "This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query."